# Eclipse file completion proposal plugin - set content type for java files

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, content-assist

I'm writing an eclipse plugin that whenever you type a string like "/usr/share" and press ctrl+space it will open up the content assist and propose you to complete files for that folder (similar to other editors.)

In my plugin xml under plugin>....extension> I have

```
<contentType id="org.eclipse.core.runtime.xml"/>
```

If I understand correctly this means that the plugin will work on files with contentType of org.eclipse.core.runtime.xml - which means xml files. 
I want my proposals to appear on .java files, or better, on any type of files.
How can I do that?

---- EDIT ----
Here is the full plugin.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?eclipse version="3.4"?>
<plugin>

    <extension
        id="completionproposal.demo.yuval"
        point="org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui.completionProposal">         

        <proposalCategory 
            id="completionproposal.demo.yuval.category"
            name="Yuval completion proposals">
        </proposalCategory>

        <proposalComputer
            activate="true"
            categoryId="completionproposal.demo.yuval.category"
            class="xmlproposals.YuvalCompletionProposalComputer"
            id="completionproposal.demo.yuval.proposalcomputer">

            <contentType id="org.eclipse.core.runtime.xml"/>            
        </proposalComputer>
    </extension>

</plugin>
```

Comment: Which extension point is this, show us the whole extension point definition

Comment: @greg-449
I added the xml. I notice that when I change my plugin and run it again, the new eclipse instance the opens up doest not change. any ideas? Is this the java contentType ?org.eclipse.jdt.core.javaSource

Comment: Yes. Note that this comment does not really help. The link has nothing to do with my question, and the google search as well. @tgkprog

Comment: okay, well i upvoted as the question is quite unique. but maybe you will have more luck email lists or blogs on the subject as there few who are into eclipse plugins

Comment: anybody know this issue? i face the same because i want to create new proposal for .drl file but i don't know what should i put on this plugin.xml file to make it run on my drl file.